# Filtering Polygon Data with many statements in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, filter

Working with QGIS 3.4.1 - Madeira

I am trying to perform a simple Filter, but when I include more than 31 values of a given field I get Zero returns.

Is there a limit to the number of statements that can be used in the filter?
I am using the following expression:
`"Field_name" = 'Value1' OR "Field_name" = 'Value2' OR`... and so on

Comment: what software are you using

Comment: QGIS... sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: If you filter from the same field try the IN operator  : "FIELD_NAME" IN ('Value1' , 'Value2' , 'Value2' , ...)

Comment: That did seems to work, thanks... do you know if there is a limit to how many 'OR' statements one can use.

Answer (score 4):

If you filter from the same field try the `IN` operator:

```
"FIELD_NAME" IN ('Value1' , 'Value2' , 'Value2' , ...)
```

It's easier to type and read and I don't think there is really a limit of the number of values (but if you need a lot of value maybe the `LIKE` or `NOT IN` operators are what you need)